# ClassNotFoundException ===> com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException

Tags: servlets, jetty, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

We are migrating to dropwizard1.x and recently faced this exception. I searched this class and found out that it was present in jersey1.x. But dropwizard1.x uses jersey2.x

Here is the stack trace of the exception:

```
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:253)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:797)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:476)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at com.cvent.eventesssync.EventEssSyncConsumerApplication.main(XYZApplication.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 70 more
```

When looked into the call stack it seem like jetty-servlet is trying to load classes when it encounters this. Jetty-servlet version is 9.4.11

I have these jersey dependencies org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-core/client/common.(2.25.1)

Why will they remove NotFoundException Class? Also Why is it getting loaded when its not required because that is why they would had removed from jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So If someone stumbles upon the same problem. I solved it by looking into code. 
I had registered some ExceptionMappers which has imported old jersey files mainly NotFoundException.

So its not a framework bug but rather unread legacy code issue.